# How can I read a pipe in the cmd.exe?

Tags: cmd, named-pipes

I was try to execute this command in the cmd.exe: echo "hi" | "spoolss"

And it was return this result: The process tried to write to a non-existent pipe.

So, How can I write in a pipe?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
echo "hi" ^| "spoolss"
```

Use ^ to escape strange characters or sometimes double them as %% to get %.
So you can write pipe ... to get ^ you write ^^.